# Nested create via JSON - validation on the nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two simple models:

```
class Idea << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks

  # for nesting....
  accepts_nested_attributes_for for :tasks
  attribute_accessible :tasks_attributes
end

class Task << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :idea
  validates_presence_of :idea # this line is causing pain
end
```

I send the following JSON to create the my IdeasController:

```
{
    "description":"Test test test",
    "tasks":[{"description":"test test test"}]
}
```

... And I get the validation error back.  As soon as I remove validation, all goes fine!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining inverse associations can help :

```
class Idea << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, inverse_of: :idea # here...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
  attribute_accessible :tasks_attributes
end

class Task << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :idea, inverse_of: :tasks # ... and here
  validates_presence_of :idea 
end
```

The reason for the validation to fail is that before this fix the association is unidirectional : when you try to reach the task's `idea`, instead of using the association proxy used to reach the task from it's idea, it creates another association proxy that is unaware of the existence of the idea (sorry, it's a bit hard to explain).

Also, be sure to use `validates_presence_of :idea` and NOT `validates_presence_of :idea_id`. Moreover, you should be using `tasks_attributes` in your json instead of just `tasks`.